# How to move API documentation to separate class?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger, swagger-2.0

Swagger provides a nice way to document REST API. However, there is one problem - documentation text above methods makes the code **looks ugly**.

E.x. I've had a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void something(@Valid @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Something") SomethingQuery query, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

and after adding some description it **looks like this**:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Do something",
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json",
            notes = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor " +
                    "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud " +
                    "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request. " +
        "This response may be sent e.x. when request is malformed or not valid or something.")})
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void something(@Valid @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Something") SomethingQuery query, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to change it in to something more **clear and readable**?

Maybe something like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = Docs.value, consumes = Docs.consumes, produces = Docs.produces, notes = Docs.notes)
@ApiResponses(value = Docs.responses)
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void something(@Valid @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Something") SomethingQuery query, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

I've tried to make it this way but it was hard to create an array of `ApiResponse`s as this is annotation.

**The best would be** to have own annotations in separate files with proper values for each field and then use them like this:

```
@ApiOperationSomething
@ApiResponsesSomething
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void something(@Valid @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Something") SomethingQuery query, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

But I don't know if it is possible.

Do any of you have some experience in separating the documentation from actual methods and making the code more clean?